# How to chain multiple send and receive operations with reactor-netty TcpClient

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I need to execute custom handshake in a TCP connection consisting of sequential send -> receive -> send -> recive and return the last receive value, but I'm having problems with chaining the execution.

Here is what I have:

```
    DisposableServer server = TcpServer.create()
            .host("localhost")
            .port(4059)
            .wiretap(true)
            .handle((nettyInbound, nettyOutbound) ->
                    nettyInbound.receive().asByteArray().flatMap(bytes -> {
                        log.info("Server inbound: {}", bytes);
                        if (Arrays.equals(bytes, new byte[]{1, 2, 3})) {
                            nettyOutbound.sendByteArray(Mono.just(new byte[]{7, 6, 5})).then().subscribe();
                        } else if (Arrays.equals(bytes, new byte[]{5, 6, 7})) {
                            nettyOutbound.sendByteArray(Mono.just(new byte[]{9, 8, 7})).then().subscribe();
                        }
                        return Mono.empty();
                    }))
            .bindNow();

    TcpClient.create()
            .host("localhost")
            .port(4059)
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 3000)
            .wiretap(true)
            .connect()
            .flatMap(connection ->
                    connection.outbound().sendByteArray(Mono.just(new byte[]{1, 2, 3}))
                            .then(connection.inbound().receive().asByteArray().next().flatMap(bytes -> {
                                log.info("bytes {}", bytes);
                                return Mono.empty();
                            })).sendByteArray(Mono.just(new byte[]{5, 6, 7}))
                            .then(connection.inbound().receive().asByteArray().next().flatMap(bytes -> {
                                log.info("bytes {}", bytes);
                                return Mono.empty();
                            }))
                            .then()
            )
            .subscribe();

    server.onDispose().block();
```

The biggest problem is that `TcpClient`'s second `receive`'s `flatMap` is not getting executed and in the logs the `wiretap` correctly shows that data was read but not emitted to that `flatMap`.

Also the logs show that client sent multiple same messages:

```
14:25:04.394 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] WRITE: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 01 02 03                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.480 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] FLUSH
14:25:04.509 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] Subscribing inbound receiver [pending: 0, cancelled:false, inboundDone: false]
14:25:04.525 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] READ: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 01 02 03                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.527 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] INFO com.example.TcpTest - Server inbound: [1, 2, 3]
14:25:04.528 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] WRITE: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 07 06 05                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.528 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] FLUSH
14:25:04.529 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] READ COMPLETE
14:25:04.529 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] READ: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 07 06 05                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.530 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] INFO com.example.TcpTest - bytes [7, 6, 5]
14:25:04.531 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] WRITE: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 01 02 03                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.536 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] FLUSH
14:25:04.536 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] WRITE: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 05 06 07                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.536 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] READ: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 01 02 03                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.536 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] FLUSH
14:25:04.536 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] INFO com.example.TcpTest - Server inbound: [1, 2, 3]
14:25:04.536 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] WRITE: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 07 06 05                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.537 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] Subscribing inbound receiver [pending: 0, cancelled:true, inboundDone: false]
14:25:04.537 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] READ COMPLETE
14:25:04.537 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] FLUSH
14:25:04.537 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] READ COMPLETE
14:25:04.537 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] READ: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 07 06 05                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.537 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] READ: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 05 06 07                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.538 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] INFO com.example.TcpTest - Server inbound: [5, 6, 7]
14:25:04.538 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] WRITE: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 09 08 07                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.538 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] FLUSH
14:25:04.538 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] Dropping frame PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 3, cap: 1024), 0 in buffer
14:25:04.539 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] READ COMPLETE
14:25:04.539 [reactor-tcp-nio-3] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0xf6dd2f6d, L:/127.0.0.1:4059 - R:/127.0.0.1:52044] READ COMPLETE
14:25:04.539 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] READ: 3B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 09 08 07                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
14:25:04.539 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] Dropping frame PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 3, cap: 512), 0 in buffer
14:25:04.539 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x3d2ab8be, L:/127.0.0.1:52044 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:4059] READ COMPLETE
```

Can someone point me to the right direction how to correctly chain `TcpClient` `send` -> `receive` -> `send` -> `receive` and return the last received value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. The reason why the solution in the questions would not work is because you cannot call `connection.inbound().receive()` twice, but only once and the whole communication flow must be handled within that call.

I wrote an article with the correct solution: [How to Implement a Custom Handshaking Protocol via TCP Using Reactor Netty](https://medium.com/@nikola.babic1/how-to-implement-a-custom-handshaking-protocol-via-tcp-using-reactor-netty-d8bcd2fe6ee7)